# RuntimeError: 'v4l2loopback' backend: std::exception when using pyvirtualcam

Tags: python, v4l2loopback, pyvirtualcam

When using pyvirtualcam, the following line

```c
with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=5) as cam
```

gives the following error

```
File "/home/linux1/Documents/jpeg-camera/./main.py", line 12, in <module>
    with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=5) as cam:
  File "/home/linux1/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pyvirtualcam/camera.py", line 219, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('\n'.join(errors))
RuntimeError: 'v4l2loopback' backend: std::exception
```

I have tried downgrading, however this does not work

Answer (score 2):

Most probably a pyvirtualcam issue. I solved it by manually specifying the device at initialization. For the example below, /dev/video**4**; if video4 is taken (`ls /dev`), pick another one. More details (assumes Ubuntu):

1. Set the device when loading v4l2loopback (`video_nr`)

`$ sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback && sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=4 card_label="Virtual" exclusive_caps=1 max_buffers=2`

2. Check you can open the device

`$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices -d4 # it should NOT say 'Cannot open device /dev/video4'`

`$ gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video4 # additional check`

3. Set the (same) device for pyvirtualwebcam

`with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=5, device='/dev/video4') as cam`

If you cannot open the stream (2. fails),  you could try compiling v4l2loopback as instructed here:
https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback

Make sure you have loaded the (new) module, it will probably end up in the `extra` folder (as opposed to the one from `apt`)

`$ modinfo v4l2loopback`
should return something like

`filename:       /lib/modules/5.16.xxx-generic/extra/v4l2loopback.ko`

If not, manally delete the old .ko and run depmod again `sudo depmod -a`